# nhibernate and generated GUI

Tags: nhibernate, user-interface

Does a framework exists that will auto generate (runtime or designtime) a simple CRUDE GUI from my nhibernate mappings and domain? Open source and in c#

Answer (score 0):

[MVC Scaffolding](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/) package is for Entity Framework, but the T4 templates are editable. You might be able to modify them to use an NHibernate session instead of the EF DBContext. Everything else generated should work pretty well.